# Size of training data is different

Tags: machine-learning, python

I am making a simple machine learning model for predicting the stock closing rate, but while splitting the test and train data the length changes.

My code:

```
X_train,y_train,X_test,y_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.4)
print(len(X_train))
print(len(X_test))
print(len(y_train))
print(len(y_test))
```

The output is:

```
3010
3010
2007
2007
```

Why is the length is changing for X and y and because of the same reason I am not able to fit it to the classifier?

Answer (score 4):

you wrote worng order for variables:

```
X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test  = cross_validation.train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.4)
```

For more information [see this](http://scikit-learn.org/0.16/modules/generated/sklearn.cross_validation.train_test_split.html)